# How to get all events associated in a zendesk tickets

Tags: python, python-3.x, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I need to get the tickets events associated for all zendesk tickets for a particular period, or in an incremental way.How can i do that.

For example if a ticket is updated 10 times a day , i need to get each of those event details .The DB i'm using is Postgres and backend language is Python.

Below is the script i use to get the ticket details, but this only gives me the last updated details of a ticket not all the events associated with that ticket.

Any help please.

```
from zenpy import Zenpy
import datetime
import json

# DB Connection
conn = get_connection("Connection String")
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tickets; CREATE TABLE tickets ( ID NOT NULL ' \
         'PRIMARY KEY, values json NOT NULL); '
cur.execute(script)
conn.commit()

# Zenpy accepts an API token
creds = {
    'email': 'email.com',
    'token': '*****************',
    'subdomain': '******'
}

time_now = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
time_now = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_now, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
one_hour_past = datetime.datetime.strftime((datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)),
                                           '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
one_hour_past = datetime.datetime.strptime(one_hour_past, '%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')

zenpy_client = Zenpy(**creds)
updated_tickets = zenpy_client.search(type='ticket', updated_at_between=[one_hour_past, time_now])
for tc in updated_tickets:
    details_json = json.dumps(tc.to_dict(), sort_keys=False)
    print(details_json)
    insert_sql = '''INSERT INTO tickets(values) VALUES ( $$ ''' + details_json + ''' $$ )'''
    cur.execute(insert_sql)
    conn.commit()
    insert_query = '''INSERT INTO tickets(values) VALUES ( $$ ''' + details_json + ''' $$ )'''
    cur.execute(insert_query)
    conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would say to take into account as you are using the incremental API here. You do have the option to utilize side loading which then opens up the ability to grab supported endpoints mentioned here (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/side_loading#special-sideloads), then you can dig a bit deeper into that to find the audits endpoint and find the audits event (https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/ticket_audits#audit-events) which gives you a farther dig into the each ticket, etc. I know this was posted a while ago and you probably have found the solution but this could prove to be helpful to some other folks who may encounter this very same issue. This is through my experience :)

Cheers,